# Example of a Bounded Linear Operator with Unbounded Spectrum.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces, spectral-theory

I was looking at this superb question posted on MSE [Spectrum can be an arbitrary subset.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399356/spectrum-can-be-an-arbitrary-subset). And this question raised the following more elementary question

> Find an example of bounded linear operator $T: X\to X$, defined in a normed vector space $X$, such that, $\sigma(T)$ is unbounded ($\sigma(T)$ is the spectrum of $T$).

I have tried to construct an example but I  have failed miserably. Moreover, I searched online but I was not able to find anything related to the question.

Does anyone know an example?

---

### Just a comment.

By  [Banach Completion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BanachCompletion.html) we can always consider $X$ as a dense subspace of the Banach space $\widetilde X$. Using the following question [extending a bounded linear operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989205/extending-a-bounded-linear-operator) there exists a unique bounded linear operator $S:\widetilde X\to \widetilde X$ such that $\|T\|=\|S\|$ and $\left.S\right|_{X}=T$.

It really seems like that $\sigma(T)\subset\sigma(S)$. If $\lambda \in \rho(S)$ (resolvent of $S$), then $(\lambda I-S)^{-1}$ is bounded. Therefore
$$(\lambda I-S)^{-1}(\lambda I-S)=\text{Id}_{\widetilde X}, $$
 if we restric the above equation to the subspace $X$ we conclude that
$$(\lambda I-S)^{-1}(\lambda I-T)=\text{Id}_{X}. $$

Since $(\lambda I-S)^{-1}$ is bounded then $(\lambda I-T)^{-1}$ is bounded as well, therefore $\rho(S)\subset \rho(T)$, then $\sigma(T)\subset \sigma(S)$. Since $S$ is a bounded linear operator in a Banach space  $\sigma(S)$  is bounded $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma(T)$ is bounded. Is this correct? (Maybe $(\lambda I-S)$ surjective  will not imply $(\lambda I-T)$ surjective).

Comment: It seems that Theorem 10.13a of Rudin's functional analysis says "no" when $X$ is a banach space (for those without the book, the theorem says that the spectrum of a member of a banach algebra is compact).

Comment: The map defined in the approved answer is not a well defined linear map. It would be nice not close this question lest this page would mislead  others.

Comment: I have removed the green check. I am really sorry. My first impression was that the example was correct.

Comment: For a bounded smooth domain $\Omega$, the Laplace operator on $H^2(\Omega)$ is bounded, but it has unbounded spectrum.

Comment: @Neal As far as I remember, $H^{2}(\Omega)$ is a Banach space if Laplacian operator is bounded this would imply that the spectrum is compact. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a very simple example, let $X$ be the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and let $T$ be multiplication by $x$.  Then $\lambda I-T$ is not invertible for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ (it is never surjective), so the spectrum of $T$ is all of $\mathbb{C}$.

All that remains is to find a norm on $X$ for which $T$ is bounded.  This is easy: for instance, you could consider $\mathbb{C}[x]$ as a subspace of $C[0,1]$ (the restrictions of polynomial functions to $[0,1]$), and then clearly $\|T\|\leq 1$.

Comment: Wow, this example is everything that  I was looking for it is really good. How did you came out with this example? Is it from some book? I am asking because I have been searching online / trying to construct one for a couple  days.

Comment: From a purely algebraic perspective, a vector space with a linear operator is just a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module, so you're looking for a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module on which $x-\lambda$ acts non-invertibly for an unbounded set of $\lambda$.  The obvious choice is $\mathbb{C}[x]$ itself, and then you just have to find a norm.